# Why to pursue or why pursue?

Tags: grammar, phrases, writing

Which of the following phrases is correct?

- Why pursue a Master's?
- Why to pursue a Master's?

Comment: ***Why bother asking**?* Have you ever heard anyone say ***Why to bother**?*

Comment: I haven't, but a colleague suggested the second writing and it does show more search hits in google (the part why pursue/why to pursue alone).

Comment: We don't include the infinitive marker ***to*** in such contexts. If this question gets migrated to ELL as per my closevote, I suggest it can be closed there as a duplicate of [Are “why doing this” and “why to do this” correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/138816/are-why-doing-this-and-why-to-do-this-correct)

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also [When should you use “to” following a “why”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174943/when-should-you-use-to-following-a-why)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should you use "to" following a "why"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174943/when-should-you-use-to-following-a-why)